# Selecting and ordering data from a query using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel and eloquent to return results based on the following query.

```
$blogPosts = BlogPosts::with('blog_user', 'blog_categories', 'blog_comments', 'tags')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(5);
```

Ok, so that is fine, it return exactly what it should, all the blog posts with associated relations to other tables.

What I now want to do is return only the $blogPosts where a tag is clicked by the user.  So let's say there is a tag "PHP", so I pass in that value as $tag to the method.  I then have something like this.

```
public function tag_search($tag)
{

    $blogPosts = BlogPosts::with('blog_user', 'blog_categories', 'blog_comments', 'tags')
        ->where('tags', $tag)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);

    $categories = BlogCategories::with('blog_posts')->get();

    $data = array('blogPosts' => $blogPosts, 'categories' => $categories,
                  );
    return view('blog.index')->with($data);
}
```

Now my issue is actually relatively simple I guess, if the where clause was a column in the BlogPosts table it would work, I know this because I tried that.

However the above won't work as is, I can only use;

```
->where('x', y)
```

Where x is a field in the `BlogPosts` table.  I want to return a set of values where the submitted $tag is the same as one associated to the tags attached to the blog posts.

Make sense?  I think I am over thinking it the point I am just not thinking now :)

Comment: I dont understand this: where the submitted $tag is the same as one associated to the tags attached to the blog posts.  

where is the problem? You can have a table with a Column named PHP and if a cell in a row has an YES saved in there, you just do the query

->where('php', '=', 'yes'

Comment: Ok but in my example above using ->where('tags', $tag) it does not recognise 'tags' as a valid column returning Unknown column 'tags' in 'where clause'.  I suspect because tags is attached within the "with" part of the statement.  So it will work fine if I put a column name in the where statement that is in the BlogPosts table.

Comment: of course, if you are using a where clause you need to have a field in the table under that name.

Comment: Indeed, what I am trying to understand is the easiest way around this, it seems that as I already have the info I want that having to rewrite a new query seems anti DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Add the column field 'tags' to your table and then these queries:

```
$blogPosts = BlogPosts::with('blog_user', 'blog_categories', 'blog_comments', 'tags')
        ->where('tags', '=', $tag)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);

     $categories = BlogCategories::with('blog_posts')->get();
     return view('blog.index', compact ('categories', 'blogposts'));
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't just add it to the table, the tags table just holds the tag names, there is a pivot table in between.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer was to use whereHas like this.

```
    $blogPosts = BlogPosts::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {

        $query->where('name', $tag);

    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(5);
```

That returns a search based on the associated elements.